# Манипуляции с блоками

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой момент: есть блок, он делится на 3 секции.

1 секция это виджиты по левому краю (например статистика, топ и тп),2секция - правый блок точно так же, а по центру собственно весь контент.

```
<div class="size">
<section class="center"></section>
<section class="left"></section>
<section class="right"></section>
</div>

.content section.center
{
    min-width:60%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content section.left
{
    width:20%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content section.right
{
    width:20%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Все отлично, становится в 3 ряда как нужно.
Теперь собственно вопрос, **подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что если я убираю например левый блок и оставляю правый**

```
<div class="size">
<section class="center"></section>
<section class="right"></section>
</div>
```

центр растягивался ?

Comment: Все отлично, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

через display:table разве что http://jsbin.com/EjuKodO/2/